# Tell cabal-install not to build in /tmp

Tags: ghc, cabal-install

I am getting exit 1 errors from `ld` when attempting to `cabal install hindent` (the actual failing package is `haskell-src-exts`). By using `sudo alternatives --config ld` to select the gold linker, and then trying again, I was able to get a more meaningful error message: `No space left on device`. Turns out `cabal install` attempts to build projects in `/tmp`, which, on my machine, is a ramdisk that is not very large. How can I tell it to build projects elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered [here](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/redirecting-cabal-install-from-tmp-td3146331.html), the solution is to set the `TMPDIR` environment variable, like so:

```
mkdir $HOME/t
TMPDIR=$HOME/t 
cabal install hindent
```